# System.Media missing assembly and no nuget package for Console Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a console game and I would like to play sounds sometimes.
After a bit of research I found that I need to use System. Media. SoundPlayer class, but unable to find the System. Media namespace. I've reached several Stack Of questions, but they were inefficient in my case.
I might notice you that I've got an error while attempting manual package addition:

`Unable to find an instance of Microsoft. VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsReferenceManager`

so I might not be able to add it manually.
I could not find a package called System. Media via VS nuget Package Explorer.

If someone could help me, I'll be highly thankful

Comment: The namespace is in the `System.Windows.Extensions` Assembly. So, you could try installing this package. `Install-Package System.Windows.Extensions -Version -5.0.0preview.6.20305.6`.

Comment: sorry i take time to answer but i'm currently updating vs19 to support 3.1 .net version for the System.Windows.Extensions Package from nuget, i hope

Comment: and i took time figuring out my vs was not compatible with >2.1 (not included) but now i think i'm on a good way, i'll come back once i have more infos

Comment: it worked, i now have access to the system.media namespace, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to gain access to System.Media namespace, you'll need to install System.Windows.Extensions nuget package as @bolkay suggested. This require >=3.0 version of .net core.